# Liferay portlet for creating web content

Tags: liferay, portlet

I use Liferay to manage web content. I would like my end users to create web content but I don't want them to go to back office to manage it.

So I would like a portlet that I can setup in public pages and which allows the end users to create web content directly in public pages.

Is there a simple way to do it using Liferay 6.1 or code is needed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Sandeep's answer is not what you're after (but I suspect it is) then you can write a custom portlet that uses Liferay's JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil methods to interact with Liferay Web Content. However I'd go with Sandeep's suggestion first as it doesn't involve coding! :)

Comment: Ok, I was afraid of that. But no matter, I will code it. Thanks.

Comment: No worries! I have found that often Liferay OOB portlets cover most of what you need to do, but often there is no way to avoid creating your own custom portlets to fulfil your requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried OOTB Web Content Display portlet? You can add Web Content Display portlet on any page and content can be created in that portlet itself which on publishing(if no workflow involved) will be visible on the page.

Comment: well, that's not exactly what I want. I would like a page with a form (and not a tiny button lost in the page), and then when the form is submited, the content goes to another page in a list.

Comment: So you are looking for entire web content management portlet that is right now available in the Control Panel on a particular page? If you are directly expecting a form where a user can add content, then it is not available OOTB. For that you need to create something custom as mentioned by Jonny.

Comment: Yes, that's something like that. A portlet that I can add to any page and that allows to choose what kind of web content to create.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develope another webcontent portlet as avaiable in control panel. You have to go for custom portlet creation and use the db tables like JournalArticle, JournalArticleImage, JournalArticleStructure and JournalArticleTemplate.

Comment: By saying "use the tables" you're saying use the Liferay API classes such as JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil etc etc and not modify the tables directly as this is a truly terrible idea.